# Why Angular does not correctly support files that are in /?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps

I am new in Angular 2+, I'm already working with on an app, using Angular version 4, I used CLI to create the project and also to serve it.

I am trying to add [manifest.json](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/) into my project, and also I tried to add a favicon, here is my code:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

I added both files in `src/` which is the root of the Angular app. When I open the app on a browser, the favicon is not showing (404) and the manifest is also not found (404).

When I put the favicon into another directory (*`src/assets/icon/`*), it worked as expected, but for `manifest.json`, it should be in the root.

What Angular is doing is very wired for me, when I press Ctrl+U on Chrome to browse the web page source code when I click on the favicon.ico or `manifest.json` link on the HTML page, it shows me the `index.html` of the Angular.

**Why is this happening?**

**How can I add my `manifest.json` and `favicon.ico` beside inside the src/ and also access them?**

Comment: `for manifest.json, it should be in the root.` for a manifest file you should be able to put that in assets or any other path just fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to define your resources in your `.angular-cli.json` file found in the root of your project.

In `apps[0].assets` you can add files for the CLI to include in the bundle. Just select the path relative from the `src/` directory. [I've included one I have for a project of mine as reference](https://github.com/MichaelSolati/ng-popular-movies-pwa/blob/master/.angular-cli.json). (Lines 10-14 are what you should look at)

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks a lot, by the way, why do I think you're Iranian? Are you?

Comment: Because you're psychic? (Yes, I am Iranian)

Comment: P.S. If you're trying to make a PWA with the CLI I have a few write ups you may like

https://dev.to/michaelsolati/pwas-with-angular-beingreliable     

https://dev.to/michaelsolati/pwas-with-angular-beingfast     

https://dev.to/michaelsolati/pwas-with-angular-being-engaging

Comment: Maybe I'm psychic, but no, I'm Iranian too, your last name was kind of familiar for me.  Thank for your good answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Correct answer for angular 12+ (probably works starting from angular 6+)**

Assets are now configured in `angular.json` under projects -> YOUR_NAME -> architect -> build -> options -> assets and support string or object values. Object values allow you to add files from the assets folder but move them to root which is required for files such as the manifest.json.

```
  "assets": [
    "src/assets",
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "src/assets/favicons",
      "output": "."
    }
  ],
```

glob: which files to select (**/* -> all)
inout: in which folder to look for the files
output: in which file should they be copied for dist

Have a look at the official documentation for more information: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration